# Pattern or idiom for safe optional bridging from Objective-C to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, null, option-type

When I call 3rd party Objective-C code from Swift, and that code is not annotated with `_Nullable`/`_Nonnull`, it's imported to Swift as Implicitly Unwrapped Optional. That means that if I'm not extra careful, I can easily cause a crash if my code just assumes it's not `nil` - the compiler doesn't even give a warnings.

Is there a pattern or idiom that will help in this situation?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the best approach, but I would make wrappers around all of the APIs, doing such things as removing IUOs, converting to/from Swift common currency types (`String` instead of `NSString`, `Array<T>` instead of `NSArray`, etc.), use Swift error throwing instead of `NSError **` parameters, etc.

Comment: Well, yes that's an option, but it's an overkill in my case.